# Lexical similarity graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data, geography

How to I make a weighted nodal graph of the all the countries in Europe and the language similarity between them.

I know the LexicalSimilarity gives the similarity of specific languages, but how would I do this for all of Europe and in a graph form where the thickness of the lines reflect the percentage of similiarity?

Here's a much smaller idea of what I'm after:

[image: Spanish lexical similarity.]

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you know how you would compute the lexical similarity of, say, Spanish and French? Because you'll need to implement that part yourself; making the actual graph will be easy afterwards.

Answer (score 10):

First grab the list of European languages.  I use Ctrl-= to find a "Country" entity class

[image]

The result has some missing values, and some languages are in there multiple times, so we clean it up a bit.

```
languages = 
 EntityClass["Country", "Europe"][EntityProperty["Country", "Languages"]] // 
    Flatten // Cases[_Entity] // Union
```

[image]

Now get the similarity data,

```
data = EntityValue[languages, "LexicalSimilarity", "EntityAssociation"] // DeleteMissing;
data//Short
```

[image]

We want to massage this into a list of weighted edges.

```
graphData = KeyValueMap[
      Function[{key, values},
       Map[
        Property[key \[UndirectedEdge] #[[1]], 
          EdgeWeight -> #[[2]]] &, values]
       ],
      data] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, (Sort @ #[[1]] &)] & //
    ReplaceAll[Interval[x_List] :> Mean[x]];
```

and then we can make a Graph,

```
Graph[graphData, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}]
```

[image]

It's interesting to look at the community graph plot for this graph,

```
CommunityGraphPlot@%
```

[image]

### Edit

We can get a slightly larger list of languages by querying the "LanguagesFraction" property,

```
Entity["Country", "Spain"]["LanguagesFractions"]
```

[image]

Though unfortunately many of these are missing the "LexicalSimilarity" property,

[image]

We can modify the definition of `languages` above,

```
languages = 
 EntityClass["Country", "Europe"][
      EntityProperty["Country", "LanguagesFractions"]] // Flatten // 
    ReplaceAll[x_Rule :> First@x] // Cases[_Entity] // Union
```

to get an expanded Graph

[image]

Comment: There are several languages missing from this list. What about Basque, Welsh, Breton, Saami, etc.?  What is the precise meaning of the Languages property for a country entity?

Comment: @Szabolcs - seems that "Languages" means ["primary languages commonly spoken"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html).  You can get some more languages with the "LanguagesFraction".  The languages you mention don't have any data for the "LexicalSimilarity" property, so they still don't make it into the final graph.

Answer (score 9):

```
languages = {"Italian", "French", "German", "English", "Spanish"} ; 
edges = Join @@ (Property[UndirectedEdge[#, #2[[2]]], EdgeWeight -> #3] & @@@ # & /@ 
  (Thread /@  Thread[{#, LanguageData[#, "LexicalSimilarity"] }] /.
    Rule -> Sequence & @ languages));
g = Graph[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort[First@#] &]@edges , 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize-> 700, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ImagePadding -> 100]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g, EdgeStyle ->  
 Thread[EdgeList[g] ->(Directive[CapForm["Round"], Thickness[#/10]] & /@ 
  Normalize[PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]])]]
```

[image]

**Update:** All European languages

```
languages = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ (CountryData[#, "Languages"] & /@ 
       CountryData["Europe"])][[All, -1]]; 
similarities = Thread /@ DeleteCases[Thread[{languages, 
 LanguageData[languages, "LexicalSimilarity"] }], {_, _Missing}] /. Rule -> Sequence;
edges = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join @@ (Property[UndirectedEdge[#, #2[[2]]], 
          EdgeWeight -> #3] & @@@ # & /@  similarities) , Sort[First@#] &]; 
g2 = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 1000, 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ImagePadding -> 100]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g2,  EdgeStyle ->  
 Thread[EdgeList[ g] -> (Directive[ CapForm["Round"], Thickness[#/10]] & /@ 
    Normalize[PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]])]]
```

[image]